# IIS express swith Off/On site in Solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-express

I have multiple Projects(site) in my Solution (visual studio 2010).

when i run my project in debug mode it runs all site in the solution.

At times i need only two or three sites.

How can i On/Off site in IISExpress so that i can avoid unnecessary load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way would be Unload that project from the solution. then it will not run in IISExpress